# GoogleSignIn Repeats Sign in Popup and doesn't go to onActivityResult for Android API 30

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I implemented Google SSO using the [GoogleSignIn](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn) for an Android App.
I usesd the sign In intent and startActivityForResult approach:
The auth flows looks like the following:

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("client_id")
            .requestServerAuthCode("client_id", true)
            .requestScopes(Scope("email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

binding.googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener{
            Timber.i("${gso.scopes}")
            val signInIntent = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)?.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
        }
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        .....doesn't matter, I tested. never reached here.
    }
```

This approach worked fine on emulator device API 29 I tested.
However, on an API 30, Pixel 3 emulator, the sign in confirm screen will repeat itself after a short loading:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0fnU.png)
After I click "Allow", the screen will become a small loading screen and this confirmation screen will reappear.

`onActivityResult` was never reached.

Also: For API 30 ONLY:
Before I added the youtube api scope in my OAuth consent screen in my google developer console,
I was getting the following behavior:

- The first confirmation page appears with all the scopes I requested
  in my gso
- I click Allow
- The second confirmation page appears with only the basic scopes[openid email profile](the youtube API scopes disappeared)
- I click Allow
- The auth flow actually completes, but now I only have the basic scope.

I also added queries in my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="com.example.myapp" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"

        android:name="com.example.myapp.application.YoutubeApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--        Main Activity-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.application.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <!--        Login Activity-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.application.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="com.example.myapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreantly there were some misconfiguration from early version, I reinstalled the app on the emulator and it solves the problem.